# CardDAV server that runs on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, webdav, addressbook

I'm searching for a simple CardDAV server that runs on Mac OS X. It could be a open source server project to compile or just some scripts to run on Apache. (I don't want to use the Mac OS X Server built in package.)

Do you have any experience with specific servers?

Which are simple and lightweight?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://trac.calendarserver.org/

Comment: I just tried that out: checkout out the svn repo, run the "./run -s" to download the requirements (about 400 MB), run the "./run" to start the server. That launches 13 subprocesses (python,postgresql,memcached,...) but it works!! :-)

Comment: But I think that is not simple and lightweight.

Comment: Actually, it's pretty simple to get up and running. Two files have to be modified of which 1) you specify the IP address and in the other 2) you specify password. Maybe it isn't light, but I'm happy, my spouse is happy, and now no matter which machine (or phone) I put something down, it gets propagated to all devices. How awesome is that?

Answer (score 2):

[SabreDAV](http://code.google.com/p/sabredav) may be be an option. (disclaimer: I'm the developer)

This question is hardly programming related though

Comment: This seems to be a better (simple and lightweight) option. But I've problems running the server (using Apache and Sqlite). May you try to help solving my problems? If yes, should be discuss this here of by email?

Comment: Best place to discuss is the mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/sabredav-discuss  I'll be there to answer any questions.